# Postgres unaccent function for character

Tags: postgresql, unicode, unaccent

I'm using unaccent in Postgres but it cannot convert special character like:
`ù : u&#x0300;` 
but it's okay for `ù: &#x00F9;` 
2 characters same meaning but different code, the first one is character u + ̀ 
How I can solve this problem ?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is [unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), what [PostgreSQL does not do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863716/unicode-normalization-in-postgres), unfortunately. And it's not so simple to implement on your own.

But, because you only want to remove diacritical marks, you only need to actually remove code-points (before or after calling the `unaccent()` function) which are [unicode combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character):

```
select regexp_replace(
  'ùù',
  '[\u0300-\u036F\u1AB0-\u1AFF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20FF\uFE20-\uFE2F]',
  '',
  'g'
)
```

should do the trick.