# How to find all relative accent in Postgresql select query?

Tags: postgresql, collation, odoo

I have a table named **contacts**

```
 id |       name       
----+------------------
 44 | Aarón
```

I am trying to execute a query :

```
select id,name from contacts where name ilike 'Aaro%';
```

It return `(0 rows)`

I am trying to search '**o**' and also expect to have result include all accent of '**o**' like '**ó**'.
As I have did some googling and stackoverlfowing I have found that using locale I need to install the collation.
So I have installed the collation in linux by

```
sudo locale-gen --no-archive de_DE.utf-8
```

after that I have tried to install collation in the postgresql database.

```
create collation de (LOCALE='de_DE.utf-8');
```

collation generated successfully. I have tried to list out this collation by using select * from pg_collation; and it is there.

after doing all this I tried again to get result of all relative accent 'o' by query:

```
select id,name from contacts where name ilike 'Aaro%';
```

but again i got `(0 rows)`

Ultimatly I want the record "Aarón" when I execute above query.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124695/postgresql-translate-special-characters or you can define by yourself.

Comment: Collation will not alter equality checks and such (like `LIKE`, `ILIKE`, `~`, etc.) but instead help you order your data with a different rule-set (some languages have strict rules for ordering accented characters). In PostgreSQL the typical solution for your problem is `unaccent()` (see the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html) module of postgres.

for that you need to install postgresql-contrib in your system. you can install it using below command in debian based linux.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

after that you can create unaccent in postgres.

```
postgres_db=# create EXTENSION unaccent;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres_db=# select name from test where unaccent(name) ilike 'Aaro%';
 name  
-------
 Aarón
(1 row)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The extension [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) is a good solution. If you deal with a small set of characters without ligatures you can alternatively use a simple function like this one for Polish:

```
create or replace function unaccent_pl(text)
returns text language sql immutable as $$
    select translate($1, 'ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ', 'acelnoszzACELNOSZZ')
$$;

select unaccent_pl('Zażółć gęślą jaźń');

    unaccent_pl    
-------------------
 Zazolc gesla jazn
(1 row)
```

Comment: `translate()` could be a good alternative, but people usually forget about [unicode combining marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) when they use it. And, no, unfortunately [PostgreSQL does not normalize unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863716/unicode-normalization-in-postgres) (yet).

Comment: As mentioned above `translate()` is of limited use. Unicode normalization is not a problem if the data come from a well-written client applications.